# What's wrong with this custom array adapter?

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to populate a listview 'Diary' with a collection of `Appointment` objects. When opening up the activity, I get a runtime exception: `java.util.NoSuchElementException`. I've been racking my brains trying to figure out how this might be happening, but as my android experience is fairly limited, I am completely stumped...

My activity code is here:

```
    DiaryAdapter dAdapter;
    DateTime currentDate;
    ListView diary;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diary);
        diary = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstAppts);

        currentDate = new DateTime();
        populateDiaryNew(currentDate);
    }

    private void populateDiaryNew(DateTime dt) {
        currentDate = dt;
        ArrayList<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
        Cursor cursor = Db.Functions.getAppointmentList(dt);
        if (cursor == null)
            return;
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Appointment appt = Db.Functions.getAppointment(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
            appointments.add(appt);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();

        ListIterator<Appointment> iter = appointments.listIterator();
        DateTime lastEndTime = new DateTime();
        int count = 0;
        while (iter.hasNext()){
            lastEndTime = iter.next().endDateTime;

            if (count > 0)
            {
                if (iter.next().startDateTime.isAfter(lastEndTime))
                {
                    Appointment freeAppt = new Appointment();
                    freeAppt.isFreeTime = true;
                    freeAppt.subject = "Free slot";
                    freeAppt.startDateTime = lastEndTime;
                    freeAppt.endDateTime = iter.next().startDateTime;
                    appointments.add(freeAppt);
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
        DiaryAdapter adapter = new DiaryAdapter(this, R.layout.appointment_info, appointments);
        //ArrayAdapter<Appointment> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Appointment>(this, R.layout.appointment_info, R.id.lblSubject, appointments);
        diary.setAdapter(adapter);      
    }
```

My custom adapter code (DiaryAdapter) is as follows:

```
public class DiaryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    ArrayList<Appointment> appointments;

    public DiaryAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Appointment> appts) {
        super(context, resource, appts);
        this.appointments = appts;
    }  

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView v1;
        TextView v2;
        TextView v3;
        TextView v4;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Appointment temp = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) { //inflate convertView and populate viewHolder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.appointment_info, parent, false);
            viewHolder.v1= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblTime);
            viewHolder.v2= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblSubject);
            viewHolder.v3= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblLocation);
            viewHolder.v4= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblCustomer);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder); //set the tag
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); //re-use the ViewHolder to     save calls to findViewById
        }
        viewHolder.v1.setText(temp.startDateTime.toString("hh:mm"));
        viewHolder.v2.setText(temp.subject);
        viewHolder.v3.setText(Db.Functions.getLocation(temp.locationId.toString()));
        viewHolder.v4.setText(Db.Functions.getCustomerName(temp.customerId.toString()));
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Appointment getItem(int position) {
        return appointments.get(position);
    }
}
```

The XML layout for the list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lblSubject"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblSubject"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblSubject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Subject"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" /> 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lblCustomer"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblCustomer"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Location"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16dp" />  

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblCustomer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblSubject"
        android:text="Customer"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblLocation"
        android:background="#333333" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally here is my logcat exception:

```
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start 

activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.DiaryActivity}: 

java.util.NoSuchElementException
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at 

android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at 

android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700

(ActivityThread.java:140)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at android.app.ActivityThread

$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage

(Handler.java:99)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main

(ActivityThread.java:4921)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative

(Native Method)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke

(Method.java:511)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit

$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main

(ZygoteInit.java:794)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 

Method)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917): Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at java.util.AbstractList

$SimpleListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:59)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at 

com.example.myapp.DiaryActivity.populateDiaryNew(DiaryActivity.java:71)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at 

com.example.myapp.DiaryActivity.onCreate(DiaryActivity.java:46)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate

(Activity.java:5206)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at 

android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     at 

android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
08-30 16:13:29.268: E/AndroidRuntime(9917):     ... 11 more
```

So I'm just trying to figure out why I'm getting this exception. I've followed a few tutorials on how to make a custom data adapter for a listview, and to my knowledge, have done it correctly. I must be missing something, but I'm not sure what.

Sorry to post a question like this but I am new to android and am completely stumped. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @Yume117 It's actually not a very long question. The chunks are mostly there for reference in case they are needed.

Comment: Did you try to use a BaseAdapter instead of arrayadapter ? Sometimes it works better for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one possible place for issue would be, following code:

You are calling `iter.next()` multiple times, but checking `iter.hasNext()` only once.

```
while (iter.hasNext()){
            lastEndTime = iter.next().endDateTime;

            if (count > 0)
            {
                if (iter.next().startDateTime.isAfter(lastEndTime))

             ............................
```

Comment: Whoops, how do I reference the current object in an iteration?

Comment: @Teifi You could store `iter.next()` in a variable, such as `Appointment element = iter.next()` and then use `element` as opposed to continuously calling `iter.next()`.

Comment: My goodness, it worked! Thank you Nambari and Josh M. There are still problems in my logic (the 'free' appointments are not appearing in the list), but at least the listview is being populated and I'm not getting any exceptions anymore :)

Comment: @Teifi: Good luck! Tahnks Josh.